# ActiveMQ Artemis Federation Hub-Spoke not working

Tags: activemq

I am trying to configure a federation of three brokers ActiveMQ Artemis (2.31.2). Let's call the brokers A, B and C.
When I configure a complete federation mesh, then a consumer of a given topic on A receives the messages sent to that topic by a publisher on C.
However, if I configure the federation as a minimal Hub-spoke  A - B - C, then the consumer on A does not receive the messages anymore from the publisher on C.
The connections between A and B, and between B and C are symmetrical upstream links.
I did not find any example configuration on the Internet for such a hub-spoke configuration. The examples that come with Artemis are all full mesh examples.
Is a Hub-Spoke configuration not possible with Artemis federation?

The topic "cms.test" is automatically created by the consumer or producer.

I used following commands as producer and consumer:

artemis producer --destination="topic://cms.test"

artemis consumer --destination="topic://cms.test"

You can find the 3 broker.xml here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Aqt2t_374ECXEVLp-n58StuPD8OuOhT1?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you provide the `broker.xml` from your A, B, & C brokers with the hub & spoke configuration?